# default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the default Authinstance can be initialized

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi I'm running into the error

> The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the default Authinstance can be initialized

I configure firebase as documentation suggests:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
      FirebaseApp.configure()
      Auth.auth().useEmulator(withHost: "localhost", port: 9099)
    return true
  }
}
```

This is the full output.

```
2023-06-14 22:56:14.626041+0930 Plants[5811:126045] 9.6.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `FirebaseApp.configure()` to your application initialization. This can be done in in the App Delegate's application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` (or the `@main` struct's initializer in SwiftUI). Read more: .
2023-06-14 22:56:14.685074+0930 Plants[5811:125835] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the default Authinstance can be initialized. One way to ensure this is to call `FirebaseApp.configure()` in the App Delegate's `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` (or the `@main` struct's initializer in SwiftUI).'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018040e7c8 __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000180051144 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018040e6d8 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
    3   Plants                              0x0000000104181234 +[FIRAuth auth] + 96
    4   Plants                              0x0000000102f05730 $s6Plants23AuthenticationViewModelC24registerAuthStateHandleryyF + 200
    5   Plants                              0x0000000102f04cc4 $s6Plants23AuthenticationViewModelCACycfc + 1696
    6   Plants                              0x0000000102f04618 $s6Plants23AuthenticationViewModelCACycfC + 44
    7   Plants                              0x0000000102f41870 $s6Plants0A3AppVACycfC + 144
    8   Plants                              0x0000000102f419ec $s6Plants0A3AppV7SwiftUI0B0AadEPxycfCTW + 12
    9   SwiftUI                             0x000000010f69ab50 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_10 + 72
    10  Plants                              0x0000000102f4176c $s6Plants0A3AppV5$mainyyFZ + 40
    11  Plants                              0x0000000102f41a00 main + 12
    12  dyld                                0x000000010a071fa0 start_sim + 20
    13  ???                                 0x0000000109e55f28 0x0 + 4460994344
    14  ???                                 0xb871000000000000 0x0 + 13290403975347044352
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the default Authinstance can be initialized. One way to ensure this is to call `FirebaseApp.configure()` in the App Delegate's `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` (or the `@main` struct's initializer in SwiftUI).'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 857.14 - Device: iPhone 14 (A63C4460-37FD-4734-8C52-6214F9519761) - Runtime: iOS 16.2 (20C52) - DeviceType: iPhone 14
```

This was working a few hours ago. I have since reinitialised the firebase emulator suite

Comment: Is `6Plants23AuthenticationViewModelC24registerAuthStateHandlery` being called before initialization? What does that file look like and what is its relation to the app delegate?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something in the app is running before the `FirebaseApp.configure` call. There may be a race condition in the app's startup code.

From the backtrace: `$s6Plants23AuthenticationViewModelC24registerAuthStateHandleryyF` is accessing Auth before the configure call.

Comment: I've followed both suggestions from the documentation to configure within the main structs init and also in the app delegate but I still get the same error? how do I approach this